# Slow Kotlin autocomplete Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android studio 4.1.3 and all Kotlin plugins updated to latest version, however autocomplete takes almost 1 second and feels very very unresponsive, this lags drops down the productivity and increase typing time.

For reference in same Android project in Java file autocomplete almost immediate.

I don't understand why it's so slow, or maybe I missed something in the configuration?

Comment: Try to invalidate cache with File->Invalidate Cache / restart

Comment: @Mikhail doesn't help

Comment: Delete your android studio and re-install it again

Comment: @George do you mean that your Kotlin autocomplete is not lags?

Comment: @PavelPoley yes my kotlin version does not lag. However, that being said please not that I also use tabnine as well in android studio

Comment: "Delete your android studio and re-install it again" - same result

Comment: kotlin 1.5 no improvements, extremely lags

Comment: upgread your kotlin.